# Thymeleaf - Accessing Nested Object Properties

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Rookie question here, I have an `<input>` that I'd like to display a User's nested property using Thymeleaf

- Each User has a Department
- Every Department has a name

I attempt to access it like by sending a `List` of User objects to my form

```
<select id="user">                      
    <option value="" th:text="-Select-"></option>
    <option 
        th:each="user: ${users}" 
        th:value="${user.id}"  
        th:text="${user.name}"
        th:attr="data-department=${user.department.name}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Thymeleaf can locate the nested department object (returns `[object, Object]`), but when trying to access the department name  a SpringExpressionLanguage Exception when trying to access the `name` of the department.

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

I'm still going through the documentation, but haven't found how to access this yet which is probably extremely simple. Any ideas?

Comment: seems to be something wrong with `department` class. could you provide the code of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, one of users has no department, hence departemnt is `null`. Thymeleaf can't get value of property of null. That's why you get error. Try to check that department is not `null` before output:

```
<select id="user">                      
        <option value="" th:text="-Select-"></option>
        <option 
            th:each="user: ${users}" 
            th:value="${user.id}"  
            th:text="${user.name}"
            th:attr="data-department=${user.department!=null}?${user.department.name}:'not specified'">
        </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: First thing I should have checked for. This worked thanks much!